# 柴門を雇うなんてチーム, 柴門なんてを雇うチーム, 柴門を雇うチームなんて

Tags: grammar, syntax, word-order

> 津田監督に逆らって柴門を雇うなんてチームはどこにもいませんよ。

The placement of なんて feels most unlikely to me. I would expect

> 津田監督に逆らって柴門なんてを雇うチームはどこにもいませんよ。

or

> 津田監督に逆らって柴門を雇うチームなんてはどこにもいませんよ。

I have always been hesitant about なんて's placement. How are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なんて *replaces* を and は, so なんてを and なんては are plain wrong. なんて is also short for などという, so 柴門を雇うなんてチーム is correct (see the 同格 usage [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6/)).

Correct expressons are:

- 柴門**なんて**雇うチーム**は**どこにもありません。
- 柴門**を**雇う**なんて**チーム**は**どこにもありません。
- 柴門**を**雇うチーム**なんて**どこにもありません。

Different words/phrases are marked with なんて, but these mean roughly the same thing, although the first one might sound most harsh to 柴門.