# でも良ければ, なんか良ければ, なんかで良ければ

Tags: particles, particle-で, particle-でも

Related to this question that I asked a while ago

[柴門を雇うなんてチーム, 柴門なんてを雇うチーム, 柴門を雇うチームなんて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93663/30454)

> 私なんかで良ければ、何でも相談に乗りますので

This seems to be the most common way to say it. But how do these alternatives sound?

> 私なんか良ければ、何でも相談に乗りますので
>
> 私なんかでも良ければ、何でも相談に乗りますので

Neither 私なんか良ければ nor 私なんかでも良ければ seem very common. I see 私なんかでも良ければ is probably a slightly different issue. So two questions:

1. Can I omit で and go with 私なんか良ければ?
2. Can I not use でも in such constructions, as in 私でも良ければ?

Comment: your second sentence sounds incorrect, but the third one sounds fine to me. Not a native though, and I also don't know the grammatical reason.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1, similar to [your recent question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94470/45489), it is independent from なんか. As far as I can think of, で can never be omitted. So the answer is no.

For 2, yes. All of the following are possible

- 私でよければ *if I suffice*
- 私なんかでよければ *if even I suffice* (being humble)
- 私でもよければ *if I also suffice* (instead of somebody else)
- 私なんかでもよければ *if even I also suffice*

Since basic nuances added by なんか and でも are similar, なんかでも may sound a bit redundant but perfectly natural.

---

The でも is a sort of mix between *even* (like 子供でもわかる) and *also* (from も).

Comment: I guess another thing which puzzles me but which I didn't include in my question was word order. So also looking at that でも question, does it mean でも always comes after the particle 海にでも (is there ででも?) and なんか・なんて before the particle (私なんかでも)? But I think I have seen になんか too. 『お前になんか惚れてない』 seems to be a book title. I think this is what I've chiefly been struggling with.

Comment: @EddieKal Re でも, I think so: it comes last. に・なんか are swappable in your お前になんか/お前なんかに ([a related chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1270793577) ). To some extent, it should be similar in English *even for you* vs *for even you*, where the latter may not be common but a similar construction is possible depending on prepositions and contexts.

Comment: FYI ででも is possible but I guess it is usually avoided due to the pronunciation difficulty. E.g. 花火がしたいなら海ででもやりなさい, normally phrased as 海にでも行きなさい.  Also the following are possible: 私になんかでもできるかな and 私なんかにでもできるかな.